# He can not come now or He is unable to come now

Tags: meaning, grammar, sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, tense

Driver informed us

> **he can not come now**
>   **he unable to come now**

Due to

> **he went to port**
>   **he went for port**

Which sentence is most suitable?

Comment: What "*port*" did he go to? Your second sentence dow not make any sense.

Comment: a town or city with a harbor

Comment: *the* driver - *the port*

Answer (score 1):

> He can not come now.
>   He **is** unable to come now.

are both correct and understandable for explaining the absence of someone

> He went to **the** port.
>   He went **down to** the port.

means that the person has gone to the port/harbor.